# Java authenticating a password

Tags: java, security, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java authentication security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332467/java-authentication-security)

I have a central `admin` instance of an app where `judge` accounts are created. In order to use this judge account, a `judge` instance of the app from another computer needs to authenticate with the central `admin`. A `user` instance of the app will send something to the `admin`, who will push it off to one of the judges.

The judges need to be able to login and authenticate with the admin. The **main** problem is that since every one will be on the same network and without SSL (I have no control over this) someone could sniff whatever the judge sends to the admin, and send that data himself and become authenticated as a judge.

Comment: Why can't you use SSL, A self signed certificate will work fine as you controll both the server and the client.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I can't use SSL because the audience of this app don't allow it. It's not something I can control.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain self signed certificates are not safe. An attacker can create the same certificate.

Comment: @siebz0r yes, self signed certificates are not trustable, *however* since you control both the client and server you make your own CA that you keep the private key safe, then put the public cert of the CA in to the keystore of your app and server then have your own private CA sign certs for the server (from what I can tell the OP don't need client authentication, so the clients only needs the CA's public cert)

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, using SSL would be the correct way.

If that is not an option, you could encrypt the content of the request yourself and assure it can only be used once.

You would need to:

- generate an encrypted token that contains the username, password and a timestamp/random value. There are some good examples on crypt/decrypt String operations on stackoverflow.
- Your server must assure, that each token can only be used once (e.g. keep a map)
- Tokens expire after a limited, small intervall ...

This will not be unhackable, but prevent regular sniffers from reusing credentials.

Comment: Thanks.

If SSL is the correct way, is there a way to use it without the end-user having to manually do anything? I am using Java's Socket based communication.

Comment: When you use root certificates, the end user will not have to do anything on his side ... its just a money issue.
As commented above, you could use self signed certs, just try to read a bit about java, socket, ssl, keystore ...

since the topic of your question is "java authenticating a password", it might be best not to continue discussing ssl-details here ...